# Where was the opening scene of Knight and Day filmed?

Tags: film-location, knight-and-day

The opening scene of [Knight and Day](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt1013743/) shows the two main characters "accidentally" bumping into each other twice, in the Wichita airport. The city of Wichita, and the state of Kansas, are mentioned many times throughout the film.  Not surprising, considering the movie was previously titled simply *Wichita*, during production ([source](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Knight_and_Day)).

However, as a native Wichitan, and someone who has flown into and out of the Wichita airport many times, I can say with absolute certainty that the opening scene of this movie was *not* actually filmed in Wichita. The Wichita airport has exactly zero escalators, despite the dozens shown in the film.

Where was this scene actually filmed? And why wasn't it filmed in Wichita, Kansas?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

According to the [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Knight_and_Day#Filming) page for this film:

> “Airport terminal scenes were filmed in Worcester, Massachusetts at Worcester Regional Airport.”

As is it extremely common for filmmakers to replace locations with 'better looking' ones (or for tax breaks) — just look at all of the *Mission:Impossible 4* scenes set in India (really Canada) — I suspect they shot *Knight and Day* at this alternate site to accommodate the script or for a touch more visual oomph.

Comment: I must agree that a film shot in the Wichita airport wouldn't be very interesting :)  With a total of 12 gates, there's not much room for adventure.

Comment: But it would be a challenge ;)

Comment: I'm sorry, not all the scenes set in India are really set in Canada. Few scenes were set in Indian cities like Bangalore and Mumbai. Especially the climax scene where main villain give orders to launch the nuke is set in Sun Network office in Bangalore. And the scenes where Tom reaches Network office in BMW are filmed in Bangalore.